# Why is TempData converting long[] to int[]

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core

ModelView...

```
public class FieldIndexViewModel
{
    //Field Field { get; set; } //maybe?
    public long Id { get; set; }
```

In my c# controller I have "Id" which is typed as `long`. This is all good.

```
        // store our fieldlist ids for prev and next iterations
        long[] tempData = FieldIndexViewModels.Select(s => s.Id).ToArray();
        TempData["FieldList"] = tempData;

        return View(FieldIndexViewModels);
    }
```

In my `get` method, FieldList is changed to `int` so the below fails with a predicate error.  The raw data shows these are now `int/int32`.

```
    // GET: Fields/Edit/5
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(long? id, int? tn, int? workPy)
    {
        // grab field list from tempdata
        List<long> FieldList = new List<long>();
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("FieldList"))
        {
            long[] ids = (long[])TempData["FieldList"];

            List<long> temp = ids.ToList(); ;

            FieldList.AddRange(temp);
        }
```

Why is TempData changing these and where?  These are showing long in the raw data before the initial method exists.

[image]

Good
[image]

Bad
[image]

Same class... not overwritten except on line 315 which is new now so I can keep coding (just casting int32 to long) for now

[image]

**** Brand new ASP core WebApp  ****
Same issue?!?

[image]

Comment: TempData by definition looks to be Dictionary<string, object> so - this error has to be from your code. Can you show the Exception/Error Message (as screenshot)

Comment: Code that you have not provided sets `TempData["FieldList"] ` to `int[]`... Make sure to provide [MCVE].

Comment: If you looking for [`TempDataDictionary` source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/TempDataDictionary.cs), there's no code which automatically converts `long` to `int` type. The most possible cause is that you're overwriting `long[]` array with an `int[]` array.

Comment: If you do `var fieldList = (int[])TempData["FieldList"];` Are you getting back the correct data?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any place to set `TempData["FieldList"]`?

Comment: Its only set at the Index method (to get all the ids).. I then go right to clicking the rows attached to the ids.  There's no logic inbetween

Comment: The data is correct.  Just wrong type

Comment: OK, the default place that .NET Core stores `TempData` is cookies. It is likely thus storing JSON, and thus deserialising as `int[]` (since JSON doesn't track the original type). You can test my theory by making one of the values in array of 3 billion (which won't fit in an int). I bet then it will be a `long[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TempData`, by default in ASP.NET Core, is serialised into cookies as BSON.

Unfortunately, storing a `long[]` as BSON (or JSON) does not remember types - so an array of longs, and an array of ints, looks exactly the same. Unfortunately, the mechanism when deserialising is [imperfect](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7114) in terms of determining the appropriate type to deserialise as.

As such, your best bet is likely to instead, use an array of a custom type (e.g. `Bob` with a public `long` property). Then serialise /encode the array as a JSON string and store that string in `TempData` (in which case it will be BSON encoded JSON!). *On the read path you'll obviously need to JSON decode the `string` from `TempData` before using it.*